# ayuda con mi error 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php

hola necesito de su ayuda con mi error en mi código:

```
<?php
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_user="nombre_de_usuario";
    $db_password="contraseña";
    $db_name="nombre_de_base_de_datos";
    $db_table_name="nombre_de_tabla";
    $db_connection = mysql_connect($localhost, $nombre_de_usuario, $contraseña)

    if(!$db_connection) {
        die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
    }
    $subs_name = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
    $subs_last = utf8_decode($_POST['apellido']);
    $subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);
    $subs_password = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);

    $resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE Email = '".$subs_email."'", $db_connection);

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
    {

        header('Location: Fail.html');

    } else {

        $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`Nombre` , `Apellido` , `Email`) VALUES ("' . $subs_name . '", "' . $subs_last . '", "' . $subs_email . '")';

        mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
        $retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

        if (!$retry_value) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        header('Location: Success.html');

    }

    mysql_close($db_connection);
?>
```

Comment: Te falta un punto y coma en esta línea: `$db_connection = mysql_connect($localhost, $nombre_de_usuario, $contraseña)` se lo puse *por error*  en la edición. Debes corregir, poniéndolo tal y como *por error*  lo he puesto en el código que ahora aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar mysqli_connect, mysql_connect ya no está soportado en la versión 7 de PHP, te dejo un enlace a la documentación de [PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php).

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="nombre_de_usuario";
$db_password="contraseña";
$db_name="nombre_de_base_de_datos";
$db_table_name="nombre_de_tabla";
$db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password,$db_name);
```